# Define a command for vectors, boldface letters, but not numbers

Tags: macros, bold

The purpose for this would be to leave scripts out of the equation. For example,

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
...
\vec{x_0}
```

would print the 0 as boldface, too. I know I can probably write

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[2][]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#2}_{#1}}}
...
\vec[0]{x}
```

But that would mean I have to reformat my whole paper, which defeats the basic purpose of defining a command.

Edit: It would be awesome to keep all scripts as original, but leave all others as-is. This would be preferable.

Comment: but, if you don't want the `0` to be bold, wouldn't it be enough to write `\vec{x}_0`? Edit: While that might also mean, you have to go through your paper again, in my honest opinion `\vec{x}_0` is the semantically correct way to write what you mean, i.e. that you have several vectors x0, x1,...

Comment: @Ronny True enough. I could rewrite the paper (about 70 kB), but it would be an awesome journey into TeX if I could see how it's done.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I think you can now look over the answers. I want to define a command that either
1) Boldfaces everything but scripts, or
2) Boldfaces letters, but not numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have made an error in typing vectors after redefining `\vec`. The subscript mustn't go in the argument.

However, if your vectors are *all* of the form `\vec{<single letter><optional subscript>}`, that is, either `\vec{v}` or `\vec{v_{0}}`, you can solve the problem by a double command:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\innervec#1}
\newcommand{\innervec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

I recommend *not* using `\ensuremath`, because vectors are undoubtedly math to me. If you have many `\vec` outside math mode, then do

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\innervec#1}}
\newcommand{\innervec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

but, for the future, restrain from using `\ensuremath` for this kind of things. You *appear* to have saved some keystrokes when typing

```
the vector \vec{v} is non zero
```

but actually you're losing information. And, anyway, you have to type

```
with $\vec{v}\ne\vec{0}$.
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @egreg that you shouldn't really use this markup, but anyway:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{{\mathbf{\xdef\zz{\textfont1 \the\textfont\the\fam}}\mathpalette\myvec{#1}}}
\def\myvec#1#2{\hbox{$#1\zz#2$}}
\begin{document}

$v_0+a+1$

$\mathbf{v_0}+a + 1$


$\vec{v_0}+ a + 1$

\end{document}
```

Comment: People seem to produce images so easily from TeX. Is there a way to do this within TeX SE or something?

Comment: @HameerAbbasi No I just take a screenshot of the pdf preview and crop it in a bitmap editor and save as png